Url-иконы в Tkinter
У меня есть 2 иконки: icon-16.png (ex.com/icon-16.png) и icon-32.png (ex.com/icon-32.png).
Как сделать так, чтобы у приложения была иконка, взятая от сайта, с помощью tkinter?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Загрузить файл с сайта в память, потом использовать где нужно в программе.

Связанный вопрос: Как в tkinter вставить картинку с сайта?

В коде `...
if response.status != 200:
label.config(text=f'HTTP error {response.status}')
else:
content = await response.content.read()
pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(content))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
label.config(image=image, text='')
label.image = image
button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)` появляются ошибки из-за отсутствия переменных label и button. Что за эти переменные?


label и button - это переменные с объектами Label и Button, очевидно. В коде в примере это вывод картинки в label и блокировка/разблокировка кнопки. Если это вам не нужно, то эти строки просто удалите.

Но картинку куда-то (например, в глобальную переменную) все равно нужно будет сохранить, иначе она удалится сборщиком мусора

Появилась ошибка в icon16 = fetch_image(url16) icon32 = fetch_image(url32) root.iconphoto(False, icon32, icon16). Сама ошибка: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'fetch_image' was never awaited

получается, для иконки нужны .gif-файлы?
